# Replace Values In a List with Multiple Rows (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been searching around for a while and not found the solution. Any help is very much appreciated!

**Problem**: I'd like to find and replace all percentage symbols ("%") in a multiple row list. The below example is a short version of my actual data which has many more rows and columns. Here's the example:

```
x = [['name', 'col1', 'col2'],
['a', '43.63%', '2'],
['b', '14.20%', '3.5%'],
['c', '10%', '3.4%']]
```

**Desired outcome**:

```
x = [['name', 'col1', 'col2'],
['a', '43.63', '2'],
['b', '14.20', '3.5'],
['c', '10', '3.4']]
```

**My code**:

```
for row in x:
    for item in row:
        item = item.replace("%", "")
print x
```

I thought this would replace each item with the new string; however, when I now print x I get the original list with "%". Please could anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually replace the item in the list.

Strings are immutable so you're creating a new item and basically not doing anything with it here:

```
# create wanted string, but where should it go?
item = item.replace("%", "")
```

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) for doing what you want:

```
for row in x:
    for index, item in enumerate(row):
        # create string *and update row*
        row[index] = item.replace("%", "")
print x
```